# Converting XML to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, xml

I know this question has been asked by few other members here but they have slightly different needs and I can't relate them exactly to my situation. So apologies for asking this again.

I have the following XML file (this is just the fist part of it)  and I need to convert it to a SQL Server table.

How do I actually do this? I am a total beginner yet trying to do somewhat a big project. I don't know much SQL and I have absolutely no idea how to read an XML file through SQL server. I want the CodeType element also to go as a column and reflect the corresponding values

```
<ReferenceDataItems CodeType="AboriginalOrTorresStraitIslanderOrigin">
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>NO</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>No</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>1</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Item>
      <CodeValue>TSI</CodeValue>
      <CodeDescription>Torres Strait Islander</CodeDescription>
      <OrderNumber>3</OrderNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <CodeValue>BOTH</CodeValue>
      <CodeDescription>Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander</CodeDescription>
      <OrderNumber>4</OrderNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <CodeValue>NOTSTATED</CodeValue>
      <CodeDescription>Not stated/Inadequately described</CodeDescription>
      <OrderNumber>5</OrderNumber>
    </Item>
</ReferenceDataItems>
<ReferenceDataItems CodeType="AccommodationType">
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>BOARDING</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Boarding house</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>1</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>TRANSITION</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Crisis, emergency or transition</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>2</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>LIVINGUNIT</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Independent living unit</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>3</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>COMMUNITY</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Indigenous community/settlement</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>4</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>INSTITUTION</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Institutional setting (i.e. residential aged care, hospital)</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>5</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>CLIENTOWNED</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Private residence - client or family owned/purchasing</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>6</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>PRIVATERENTAL</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Private residence - private rental</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>7</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>PUBLICRENTAL</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Private residence - public rental</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>8</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>PUBLICSHELTER</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Public shelter</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>9</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>SUPPORTED</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Supported accommodation</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>NOTSTATED</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Not stated</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>11</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <CodeValue>OTHER</CodeValue>
    <CodeDescription>Other</CodeDescription>
    <OrderNumber>12</OrderNumber>
  </Item>
</ReferenceDataItems>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your entire XML data in a variable called `@xml`, then you can use this XQuery code to extract the details information:

```
SELECT
    CodeType = XC.value('@CodeType', 'varchar(50)'),
    CodeValue = XC2.value('(CodeValue)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    CodeDescription = XC2.value('(CodeDescription)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    OrderNumber = XC2.value('(OrderNumber)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/ReferenceDataItems') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('Item') AS XT2(XC2)
```

This will return a dataset something like this:

[image]

How you want to insert this into which table is not clear from your question - you need to figure that out yourself.....

Comment: Thank you so much! First of all, sorry I don't know how to accept the edits  you performed on my post. I pressed rollback and it went to the old post style.

Sorry as I was saying I'm new to the game. Should I run SQL server and fire up this query as a new query? 

I want to put them in to a table call 'ReferenceData'

Also, is this where I suppose to put the path of the XML file? 
('/ReferenceDataItems')

Comment: @RandikaWijekoon: you don't need to *accept* anything - just leave the post as it is - edited and more readable. **DO NOT** rollback.....

Comment: **(1)** you need to **load** the XML into a SQL Server variable - Google for that, there's tons of resources showing you how to do this. Then **(2)** you need to be sure you have all the necessary columns in your `ReferenceData` table, and then **(3)** you can use `INSERT INTO dbo.ReferenceData(CodeType, CodeValue, CodeDescription, OrderNumber) SELECT ......` (and use the `SELECT` above as the *source* for your `INSERT` statement)

Comment: Thanks so much Marc! You are a champion! I was going to manually type the data :)  . This saves so much time and I learnt something new. Much appreciated my friend!